# React table is getting sorted on filter

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, react-table, react-table-v7

I am creating a grid for my project where I need to implement column filtering. I have done it mostly, but facing an issue, that is whenever I click on the filter input box for ID column that column gets sorted. I have tried using `e.stopPropagation()` but that is not working.

A working copy of my code base can be found at https://4hz20.csb.app/, and the code is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/data-table-forked-4hz20

ColumnFilter.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Input = styled.input`
  width: 144px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #c2c3c9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
`;

export const ColumnFilter = ({ column }) => {
  const { filterValue, setFilter } = column;
  return (
    <Input
      value={filterValue || ""}
      onChange={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setFilter(e.target.value);
        return false;
      }}
      placeholder="Search"
    />
  );
};
```

additionally I am using `manualFilters: true`, `manualSortBy: true` and `manualPagination: true` as I want to handle them on server-side, but manual sorting and manual filter does not seem to work together, refer `DataGrid.js` line 37-39.

Answer (score 8):

I changed the code from

```
<th scope="col" {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
    {column.render("Header")}
    <span>
        {column.disableSortBy ? "" : column.isSorted n? column.isSortedDesc ? " " : "  " : " ⇵"}
    </span>
    <div>
        {column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}
    </div>
</th>
```

to

```
<th scope="col">
    <div {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
        {column.render("Header")}
        <span>
            {column.disableSortBy ? "" : column.isSorted n? column.isSortedDesc ? " " : "  " : " ⇵"}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        {column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}
    </div>
</th>
```

Wrapped the desired elements in a div and passed `{...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}` to it.

Comment: Hi Polly, I am stuck with one issue in React which is related to sorting of rows in React-Table - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68359658/1649217

Answer (score 0):

I started with @Polly Banerjee solution to get filtering and sorting work on the same column, but realized I still need some of the column properties to remain on the row tag as opposed to on the div. This worked for me (using Material example):

```
<TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
          {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
            <TableCell
            {...column.getHeaderProps([
              {
                className: column.className,
                style: column.style,
              },
              getColumnProps(column),
              getHeaderProps(column),
            ])}
            >
            <span {...column.getHeaderProps([
                column.getSortByToggleProps()
              ])}>
              {column.render('Header')}
              {column.id !== 'selection' ? (
                <TableSortLabel
                  active={column.isSorted}
                  // react-table has a unsorted state which is not treated here
                  direction={column.isSortedDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc'}
                />
              ) : null}
              </span>
              {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
              <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
```